# How can I create a javascript array froma range in a google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I want to take a range from a Google spreadsheet, create a javascript array and then pass each item, form the range, into the array.

The values in the range (A5: A10) are, for example, bitcoin-cash, litecoin, ethereum, monero, dash, quantstamp.

My code is as follows:

```
function appendCoins() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var r = sheet.getRange('A5:A10').getValues();
  var coins = [];
  for (var i=0;i < r.length-1;i++) {
     coins.push(r[0][i]);
    }
    Logger.log(coins)
}
```

The logger shows me this:

```
[18-01-10 18:09:07:218 GMT] [bitcoin-cash, null, null, null, null, null]
```

So the first one is correct, it loops the correct number of times but all the other values are undefined.

Why is this? It should be straightforward. Can anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: I'd be tempted to throw in a console.dir(r) just before "coins.push(r[0][1])".

Comment: @AnthonyHaffey: Doesn't Google Sheets have a proper debugger?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - maybe I'm just making a n00b suggestion on how to debug in this instance. Just the way that seemed easiest to me to work why null values were coming out.

Comment: @AnthonyHaffey: I was really hoping you were going to say "yes, it does" and point me at it. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It does, see https://console.cloud.google.com/debug, but you need to have deployed applications to use it, just a Google Apps script seems not to show up in the drop-down list.

Comment: @vinnief - *"It does"* Yay! *"just a Google Apps script seems not to show up"* :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns the range indexed by row, then column. Your range, A5:A10, has five rows and one column. You're treating it as though it had one row and five columns. Swap `0` and `i` in your code:

```
function appendCoins() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var r = sheet.getRange('A5:A10').getValues();
  var coins = [];
  for (var i=0;i < r.length-1;i++) {
     coins.push(r[i][0]);
  }
  Logger.log(coins)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, correct. Silly me. Very grateful. I will accept answer in 7 minutes!